# How can i Insert data to database using php and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to insert data to the database I have getting menuId from mconfig table and I need to insert a table to menugrades table I have array value I think but how to insert data to the database table.

This is my Query code:

```
 $validmenuId =   $this->db->select('menuId')
                      ->where('id',  $params['configid'])
                      ->where('isArchived is NULL')
                      ->get('mConfig')
                      ->result_array();

 print_r($validmenuId);

 $this->db->insert('menugrades',$validmenuId);
```

Note:
If I printing the data it's coming like this.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [menuId] => 474
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a single record so use `row_array()` instead of `result_array()`  see as below

```
$validmenuId =   $this->db->select('menuId')

                 ->where('id',  $params['configid'] )

                 ->where('isArchived is NULL')

                 ->get('mConfig')->row_array();

          $this->db->insert('menugrades', ['menuId' => $validmenuId['menuId'] ] );
```

Comment: Hi Devsi Thanks,

Comment: Hi, Instead of same that i have to pass the variable to another query please see my code :  $validcampusId =   $this->db->select('campusId')
                    
       ->where('id', $validmenuId['menuId'])

        //->where('accountId', aid())

         ->where('isArchived is NULL')

          ->get('menu')

           ->row_array();
           

           
        $this->db->insert('menugrades', ['menuId' => $validmenuId['menuId']'campusId' => $validcampusId['campusId'], ] );

Comment: Hi Devsi Thanks for your Kind of help.It's Working fine

Comment: @Rajkumar you can pass multiple or row array directly